# Why the pointy block with Match in for loop output Nil?

Tags: regex, raku

A valid [Match object](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match) is not empty or undefined in my opinion:

```perl
say Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)).elems;   # 0
say Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)).chars;   # 2
say Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)).defined; # True
```

but the following pointy block with a `Match` object in a `for` loop outputs `Nil`:

```perl
for Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)) -> $m {
    say ~$m
}
# OUTPUT: Nil
```

But the `given` statement outputs what I expected:

```perl
given Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)) -> $m {
    say ~$m
}
# OUTPUT: 02
```

Isn't something empty or undefined that prevents a `for` loop from executing?

```perl
for "a" -> $m { say $m } # a
for []  -> $m { say $m } # Nil
for {}  -> $m { say $m } # Nil
```

Comment: "A valid `Match` object is not empty or undefined in my opinion". One must be careful with definitions here. In Raku "empty" has a particular meaning that means some object such as an array or hash or match object has no *elements*. If a `Match` object does not include captures (*child* `Match` objects) then it has no elements and is thus "empty".

Comment: What Rakudo version are you on? And can you give us a little code to check out ourselves? Something like: `raku -e '"20230213112803".match(/02/).raku.put;'` Or are you creating `Match.new` objects yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** `given` will *always* treat its argument as *one* thing (an object). In contrast, `for` is a looping construct, and may ask its argument to `.list` its elements so it can usefully loop. It does so in your example, and the `Match` object contains no elements, so the `for` doesn't call the block at all.

## `given foo` (or `given foo, bar`)

`given` just makes its argument(s) the topic ("it") and calls the associated statement or block (passing in the topic). End of story.

## `for foo, bar`

`for foo, bar` just makes each of its arguments the topic in turn (and calls the associated statement/block). Again, end of story.

## `for foo`

If `for` only has one argument, and that argument is not explicitly marked as singular (by prefixing it with `$`), then `for` calls `.list` on that argument and, for each value in the returned list it sets that to "it" and calls the associated statement/block, one-by-one. That's your scenario. Again, end of story.

Except this clearly confused you (and Liz), so there needs to be a bit more to my answer!

---

Like an array or a hash, a [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture) (and thus `Match`) object may contain zero or more elements. In all these cases *the object itself is not an element*.

A Rakoon is not surprised when `for [] { ... }` does nothing, because the `[]` very obviously contains no elements, and it would be kinda silly, not to mention confusing, for the array to return itself as if it were an element of itself.

What about `for Match.new { ... }`? It also does nothing, and it's perhaps obvious why not -- because it also contains no elements.

But what about your example? Well, again, it does nothing, and again, it's because it contains no elements.

But "what?!?" you say! Surely the match object is itself useful data? Why doesn't the `for` treat it like it would, say, `for 42 { ... }`? Well, because if you absolutely want that, then write `given 42 { ... }` instead. If you use `for`, then expect Raku to seek out a *list* meaning for its argument(s), not a singular meaning, and that means calling `.list` on its argument in the scenario in your question.

Then what *are* a `Match` object's *elements*? They are its *child* `Match` objects, if any. There may be *positional* ones (which you can access with, for example, `match-object[...]`, or `.list`), and *named* ones (which you can access with, for example, `match-object{...}` or `.hash`).

Comment: `for Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6), :list(( Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)),))) -> $m { say ~$m } # 02` 
When there is a `Capture` in regex,  there will be a `:list` pair parameter in the `Match` object, Which is `Match` object's elements. In this example, it's positional.
Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Let's back up a second. Why create `Match.new` objects when something like `substr` seems easier and faster?

Answer (score 1):

I think if Raku returned an error stating that match was not iterable, you might have less of a problem.  It seems that the "for" construct will ask the match object for a list.  There are no submatches defined in your example, so you get an empty list.

Perhaps if you were to place the match object into a list, then you'd get what you were expecting - the first item in the list would be the match object:

```
for (Match.new(:orig("20230213112803"), :from(4), :pos(6)), ) -> $m { say $m }
```

Another alternative is that you expected to actually perform a match and iterate over multiple matching bits..

Comment: A `Match` **is** iterable in standard Raku. It would be an error for standard Raku to display an error rather than operate the same way all other Raku objects do. I tried to explain that in my answer (and will try to improve it). `Match` does *not* do the `Iterable` role because it chooses not to commit to that role statically, preferring to instead present itself as a single object in general, and only revealing its iterable contents if asked to do so dynamically. This scheme reflects the nature of `Match` objects, which are involved in string matching, an inherently run-time operation.

Comment: It's OK if  there is a `Capture` in the regex. An your `for tuple` answer is interesting.Thanks

Comment: Interesting @raiph - I was more talking about the OP's expectations, but your extra comments are also a great addition.  Your answer was fine - I mention the fact that a valid empty list is returned in my answer also.